# How can I resolve phpcs and vscode issue on Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code, cygwin, phpcs

I've been battling to get PHP CodeSniffer to work on VSCode, always unable to locate phpcs, which i've installed globally. Adding the executable path to phpcs errors with:

`failed to open stream: No such file of directory in /cygdrive/c/Users/{Username}/local_sites/{site_name}/public/c:\cygwin64\home\{username}\.composer\vendor\squizlabs\php_codesniffer\bin\phpcs` which is a concatenation of my local web server home directory and the executable path.

I think I need to use a symlink, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Are you mixing cygwin and windows program ? phpcs is not a program available on the Cygwin distribution, how you built or installed it ?

Comment: I installed using composer, it seems to be working from command line.